# React-why event target value is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a shared component, which is an input textarea

The component is:

```js
class TextBox extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
    const value = this.props.value;
    this.state = {
      value: value
    }
  }
  
  handleChange(e, v) {
   console.log("event: ", e);
   this.setState({value: e.target.value}, () => {this.props.handleChange(e, v)});
  }

  render() {
    const {
      name
    } = this.props;

    const {
       value
    } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
         <h2>{name}</h2>
         <textarea
           value={value}
           onChange={this.handleChange}
         />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Using this component:

```js
   const [comment, setComment] = useState('');
   const handleChange = useCallback((e, v) => {
      setComment(v);
   }, [comment]);

    ....
    <TextBox 
      name="comment"
      value={comment}
      handleChange={handleChange}
    />
```

The console log shows event.target.value is undefined
I have no idea why, can someone help? Thanks in advance

===update===
Thank you all! The problem is fixed

Comment: You're not accessing `event.target.value`, you're accessing a non-existent parameter `v`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be `target` and `value` from the first parameter:

```js
  handleChange = (e) => {
   console.log("event: ", e);
   console.log("value: ", e.target.value);
    this.setState({value: e.target.value}, () => {this.props.handleChange(e, v)});
  }
```

Inside the above function:

- `e` - `Window.Event`
- `e.target` - `<textarea>` element in JS.
- `e.target.name` will be the `name` attribute.
- `e.target.value` will be the `value` attribute.

Also I'll suggest you to use Arrow Functions, else you might need to bind the function to `this` on the constructor, which is not being followed now-a-days.

Comment: Hello, question description is updated.  event.target.value is still not there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind the `handleChange` function in constructor like below:

```
this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

You can also use arrow function like this way:

```
handleChange=(e)=>{//...content here}
```

Also, there is no such parameter as `v`. The only parameter should be `e`.